Extracting Snakemake metadata (filenames) with the Snakemake API
I am creating a program that can store all relevant data from a Snakemake analysis run into a gzipped file (or a Pickle, not sure yet), for easy backup and moving around different machines.
To do this, it would be very helpful I I could somehow use my samples.tsv file and the Snakefile (the rules) to create a list of all files that are created in the entire data processing pipeline. I just want a list of all files created, per sample, during a workflow.
I was wondering if that is perhaps possible to do with the Snakemake API. I see some functions that seem useful but I don't quite understand the documentation without examples.
Can anyone help? Are there perhaps other ways to achieve the same thing? I could write something myself of course (parse all filenames from the rules), but I think this must have been created before...
Thank you.
Edit: Providing some more details of what I am looking for, for example I would like to do this:
import snakemake.api

workflow = snakemake.api.SnakemakeApi.workflow(
  'path/to/Snakefile',
  'path/to/config',
  'path/to/samples.tsv'
  )

workflow.files_created_in_workflow

>

[
  'expression/SRR29098682.genes.results',
  'expression/SRR29098675.genes.results',
  'expression/SRR29098683.genes.results',
  'qc/SRR29098682.rseqc.fragment_length.txt'
 ...
]

Etc, so that I can then use that list of files to gzip them all together (after excluding some large files like .bam and .fastq.gz), preferrably on a per sample basis.
